# c# Add System.Data.DataSetExtensions to .net core web api application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, datatable

I am new to .net core api. I want to use `AsEnumerable` on datatable and need to add 
`System.Data.DataSetExtensions` as reference to my project. I don't see a reference section under my project.

It seems like i need to edit my csproj file. This is how my csproj file looks now.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.Dapper.Plus" Version="1.3.26" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How can I add `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to my existing project? Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/

So add a PackageReference to your project:

```
 <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This was stupid of me. I was able to get from nuget.